# Are there any ways to refresh a listview every 5 or 3 seconds without using the timer?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, listview

I have a form which is running on the other laptop, this is the kitchen side where all the orders will go through after buying in my POS (which is running on the other laptop also) side.

Now my listview in the kitchen side refreshes after 5 seconds 'using the timer', are there any options or ways to refresh the listview without using the timer so that the 'Focus' when I select an item inside the listview will not disappear?

This is the my code:

```
public Kitchen()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    listView2.Columns.Add("ORDERS", 800);

    listView2.View = View.Details;
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer_1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer1.Interval = 5000;
    timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Start();
} 

private void dinein(String tblnmber)
{
    String[] row = { tblnmber };

    listView2.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(row));
} 

public void loaddinein()
{
    listView2.Items.Clear();
    string sq = "select tblnmber as [ORDERS] FROM Kitchen Group By tblnmber";

    cmd = new SqlCommand(sq,con);

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            dinein(row[0].ToString());
        }

        con.Close();
        dt.Rows.Clear();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        con.Close();
    }
}  

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loaddinein();
}
```

Comment: In your dinein you could get the current selected index in the list and after adding the new item reselect that item

Comment: Consider using [`SqlDependency`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency) so that an `OndependencyChange ` event handler is invoked when the query result sets change. To use `SqlDependency`, Service Broker needs to be enabled in the database and schema-qualified names (e.g. `[dbo].[ORDERS]`) must be used in the query.

Comment: I am going to learn this Sql Dependency, Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your question is really *how do I refresh an existing list of items without changing order or focus?* **not** *anything to do with timers*.

To accomplish that when you fetch the data from the DB again, you need to determine which items have changed in the list (compare the text of your model to an item in the list) and simply update the **Text** of those items.  Overwriting a `ListViewItem`'s Text property won't change selection/focus or re-ordering by default.

**Don't** clear out the `ListView` and repopulate otherwise focus/selection will change.

A timer is still perfectly valid to use.

Comment: @stxy No problem.  Don't forget to upvote and accept the appropriate answer

Answer (score 0):

Pooling continuously to the DB server is not a good approach, you can go for either of the two approaches.

1. Raise a change message using trigger to `MSMQ`, and subscribe to the
   `MSMQ` for new messages. For more details on the implementation you
   can check [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/555070)
2. Monitoring the data changes using `SqlDependency`, for more details you can check [here](https://blog.jsinh.in/monitoring-data-change-using-sqldependency-and-c/#.XGAID1UzbIU)

Note: Both the approaches have it own pro/cons. For example if the number of listeners are more, in that case SQL Dependency will hit the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys i've already watch and read some tutorials , and implement it, unfortunately sql dependency is not firing to my datagridview nor listview. I've also enabled the broker.

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
//ALTER DATABASE HOB SET ENABLE BROKER
namespace DemoSQL
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string m_connect = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-3B561M1;Initial Catalog=Users;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = null;
        public delegate void NewHome();
        public event NewHome OnNewHome;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            try
            {
                SqlClientPermission ss = new SqlClientPermission(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted);
                ss.Demand();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            SqlDependency.Stop(m_connect);
            SqlDependency.Start(m_connect);
            con = new SqlConnection(m_connect);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnNewHome+=new NewHome(Form1_OnNewHome);//tab
            //load data vao datagrid
            LoadData();
        }

        public void Form1_OnNewHome()
        {
            ISynchronizeInvoke i = (ISynchronizeInvoke)this;
            if (i.InvokeRequired)//tab
            {
                NewHome dd = new NewHome(Form1_OnNewHome);
                i.BeginInvoke(dd, null);
                return;
            }
            LoadData();

        }

        //Ham load data
        void LoadData()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            if (con.State==ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }      

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FirstName,LastName from dbo.Uss", con);
            cmd.Notification = null;

            SqlDependency de = new SqlDependency(cmd);
            de.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(de_OnChange);

            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection));
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        public void de_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDependency de = sender as SqlDependency;
            de.OnChange -= de_OnChange;
            if (OnNewHome!=null)
            {
                OnNewHome();
            }
        }
    }
}
```